# Binding Linq To Entities query results to a datagridview

Tags: linq-to-entities

I just started playing with Linq to entities in a windows forms application and am not understanding one behavior that looks so simple though.

If i type code below, i get ReadOnly records in my dataGridView

```
Dim x = From n in Table1 _
        Select n.FirstName, n.LastName, N.Department
DataGridView1.DataSource = x
```

But if i type the following code, i get editable rows in my dataGridView

```
Dim x = From n in Table1 _
        Select n
DataGridView1.DataSource = x
```

So, basically if i specify the column names to select and databind to my DataGridView1, the rows are readonly but if i do not specify the column names and databind to the DataGridView, the rows are editable and i don't understand why.

Comment: Well, yes, anonymous types are immutable. What do you expect?

Comment: Not in VB.NET, according to documentation. (I'm not sitting at a compiler right now.)

Comment: In VB.NET, they're, um, both: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/10/01/drill-down-on-anonymous-types.aspx

Comment: Well, yeah, I have a bit more detail in my answer. :/ Good article though. I searched and searched and must have missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yztkd864.aspx) about this.

After a little searching and lots of editing my answer, it seems like the culprit must be [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx). The documentation indicates that the non-key fields of anonymous types should be read-write, but you might be invoking some kind of exception to this rule. I would debug in and check the exact type of x in both cases.

There's another possible hint in  [this blog entry by someone](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2007/05/11/20566.aspx). "The LINQ query expressions will automatically use Key fields in any situation where a key is going to be generated (for example, Group By), [...]" It might be that fields created by using the `Select` method are automatically Key properties.

Another [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105056/linq-vb-anonymous-type-cannot-be-converted-to-anonymous-type) hints at this - they match the type of some results from a Select method call by putting `Key` on the fields of the other type.

**Edit: And [this article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/10/01/drill-down-on-anonymous-types.aspx) (thanks, Greg Stuntz) comes right out and says it. Geez.** "You can simplify the anonymous type definition when writing a LINQ query by omitting the New With and the { }'s, but be aware this creates fully immutable types."